# How to use Insert in Set for Custom Data Type ? C++

Tags: c++

```
class Game()
{
 void add(set<Velocity> & v); 
}
class Velocity()
{
private:
  // Member Variables 
public:
   // Constructors and methods 
}
```

```
void Game::add(set<Velocity> &velocities)
{
   Velocity v;

   v.setVelocity(); 
   v.setSource();
   velocities.insert(v); 
}
```

As you can see I have a custom class called Game and it has a public method called Add which adds a velocity object to the set. When the insert(v) code executes it throws me an error: invalid operands to binary expression ('const Velocity' and 'const Velocity')
{return __x < __y;}

I am not sure how to fix this, I would appreciate any help or suggestions. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: Items in a set must be `<`-comparable. Write a `operator <` for `Velocity`.

Comment: I would appreciate it a lot if you were able to provide an example. Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [std::set.insert won't compile with custom class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15913857/stdset-insert-wont-compile-with-custom-class). Dupe2 [Cant insert to std::map (G++)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15868776/cant-insert-to-stdmap-g). Dupe3 [problems with c++ set container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14784620/problems-with-c-set-container)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In [`std::set`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set)...

> sorting is done using the key comparison function...

You need to look toward something like this:

```
bool operator<(const Velocity&, const Velocity&);

class Velocity {
friend bool operator<(const Velocity&, const Velocity&);
private:
    unsigned velocity_value;
    // ...
};

bool operator<(const Velocity& a, const Velocity& b)
{
    return a.velocity_value < b.velocity_value;
}
```

Note, however that in this example, there won't be possible to have two different elements of type `Velocity` with the same `velocity_value`, since...

> std::set is an associative container that contains a sorted set of
> **unique** objects of type Key

If you need to add all the supplied `Velocity` objects in an instance of the `Game`, you may need to reconsider the choice of the container, or some other mean of comparison.